# Number of articles in multiples sub-categories

Tags: articles, joomla-4.x, mod-articles-category

I use mod_articles_category to display a list of categories with their articles.

I need to display the total of articles next to each category title.
I've tried with `<?php echo $item->numitems; ?>` - found in com_content/categories - but it doesn't help.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Layout\LayoutHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Helper\RouteHelper;


if (!$list) {
    return;
}

?>

<ul class="row">
    <?php if ($grouped) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($list as $groupName => $items) : ?>
  
        <div class="col">
        <li>  
               
            <div class="mod-articles-category-group fs-3 fw-bold"><?php echo Text::_($groupName); ?>                 
                <span class="ps-3 text-muted fw-light fs-5"><?php echo $item->numitems; ?> articles</span>                   
            </div>
            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
            
                <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
                <li class="py-2">
                    <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') == 1) : ?>
                        <?php $attributes = ['class' => 'mod-articles-category-title ' . $item->active]; ?>
                        <?php $link = htmlspecialchars($item->link, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false); ?>
                        <?php $title = htmlspecialchars($item->title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false); ?>
                        <img src="images/svg/caret.svg" alt="" width="13" height="13" class="pe-2"><?php echo HTMLHelper::_('link', $link, $title, $attributes); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </ul>
            <p class="ms-3 pt-3"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right pe-2"></i>See all articles about 
                <span class="mod-articles-category-category">
                    <?php echo $item->displayCategoryTitle; ?>
                </span>
            </p>
        </li>
         </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php $items = $list; ?>
        <?php require ModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_articles_category', $params->get('layout', 'default') . '_items'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want it with an override but if not really needed you can do easily with Article Anywhere plug-in and [count] info ;-)

Comment: Yes I want to acheive this with an override, not with an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `count($items);` in the loop to get the number of items:

```
        <div class="ms-3 mod-articles-category-group fs-3 fw-bold"><?php echo Text::_($groupName); ?>                
            <span class="ps-3 text-muted fw-light fs-5"><?php echo count($items); ?> articles</span>                 
        </div>
```

Comment: Please include an educational explanation with this snippet.